# Delete post by id fails everytime

Tags: php, sql, button, while-loop, sql-delete

I have a newsfeed where people can upload things, and on there I have a *delete* button. I read a few techniques you could do to delete a row from the database.

I used this one by using input type hidden field etc.

**HTML**

```
<form action="logic/delete_post.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="?id='.$pica['img_id'].'" />
<input type="submit" name="deleteSubmit" value="Delete" class="delete_post" />
</form>
```

**DELETE_POST.PHP**

```
<?php


if(isset($_GET['deleteSubmit'])) {

    $img_id = substr($_GET['id'],4,6);

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT picas.img_id FROM picas WHERE username='$ses_user'");
        $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM picas WHERE img_id='$img_id'");

        if (mysqli_affected_rows() == 1) {
        echo 'Succes!';
        } else {
            echo 'Damn!';
        }
    }

}


?>
```

Every comment with help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't see php brackets in the value attribute, or I guess you are echoing out entire junk of html as you are using concatenation..

Comment: You're never setting `$img_id` before using it to delete images.

Comment: Also, your code is not efficient, your users can inject any data as you are not validating the ids at all

Comment: You get an error message? Is $img_id set?

Comment: Also, you are using OOP style for execution of the query and are using a procedural function to check affected rows. You should be checking that with ` $mysqli->affected_rows`

Comment: And your first query is useless, its result is not being used anywhere in the code

Comment: The form is already in an echo so it is good, I know that, but I am trying to fix the PHP. Guys... try to help me what I can do and not say how useless things are.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the questionmark:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="?id='.$pica['img_id'].'" />
                                      ^
```

And make this look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$pica['img_id'].'" />
```

Then

```
$img_id = $_GET['id'];
```

And addslashes() should be used if this is not enabled in PHP.ini for request values.